# Is it possible to modify Geth source code to send other signed transaction than one the sender has done?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

Suppose there are two Ethereum nodes (A and B) that both are using Geth to interact with the network. Is it possible a malicious player can manipulate the source code of Geth so that each transaction that A intends to send it ,to B by Geth, replaced by the player's desirable transaction, and then the latter be sent to Ethereum? However, A can check the the transaction receipt and ledger and understand  the malicious action but I need to know does have Geth such ability or not?
I don't know is my question right or not? because I'm blind about Geth source code.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

Your question doesn't make complete sense, although I feel that you are erring towards [re-entrancy](https://hackernoon.com/hack-solidity-reentrancy-attack) rather than a bug/ability in Geth.

To be clear on my misunderstanding of your question: Ethereum nodes dont use Geth to interact with the network, rather Geth is a client that allows interaction with Ethereum nodes, wether a local node (such as in Ganache), a testnet (e.g. Goerli) or mainnet: modifying source code for a client would just mean that any sent transactions are not accepted by miners on the network.

Comment: Thanks, So you say one can't embed an unwanted transaction in Geth source code, yes?